# How to run a script constantly in background under linux

Tags: linux, debian, perl

I have a perl script which runs a mini webserver allowing me to do various things. I'd like to have this script run when the machine starts up, and constantly run in the background.

How should I achieve this? I want the script to regardless of whether anyone is logged in or not, so I can't put it in any bash-related files.

I'm using Debian, if that affects things (which it probably will)

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

You will want to use the `init` facility (`/etc/rc.d`) or [`daemontools`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html). If it's a recent version of Debian, you can use [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: I don't believe upstart is considered stable yet on Debian. It should only be used by extremely experienced users.